# How to pause a timer created with CreateTimerQueueTimer

Tags: c, winapi

I need to pause a timer created using CreateTimerQueueTimer function of win32 API but I can't find a way to pause the timer.
Does anybody knows if it is possible?

Comment: No pause option, you can only stop it and start it back up.  That does require measuring how much time has elapsed at the moment you pause it.  Use GetTickCount64() when you start it, again when you pause it.  Do beware it is fundamentally racy, you might discover that it has already expired but not made its callback yet.  In which case it is best to do nothing.  Now you know why it doesn't have a pause option :)

Answer (score 5):

I believe you can call [ChangeTimerQueueTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682004(v=VS.85).aspx) and set the `_In_     ULONG  Period` to 0. Where the `_In_opt_ HANDLE TimerQueue` argument will be `NULL` and the `_Inout_  HANDLE Timer` will be the HANDLE retrieved from [CreateTimerQueueTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485(v=vs.85).aspx). This will execute the callback in the timer just once and stop. If you want to reactivate the timer you can `ChangeTimerQueueTimer` again with the same handle providing a period greater than 0 to run periodically. There isn't specifically an API to suspend the timer but preventing it from running periodically should be the equivalent in your case. Just note that your callback will get hit once after calling `ChangeTimerQueueTimer` before "suspending".

Comment: `DueTime` is just delaying the initial execution. "DueTime [in]
The amount of time in milliseconds relative to the current time that must elapse before the timer is signaled for the first time." There could be instances where a person wants to activate the timer instantly then pause at any random time in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!. It's a good approach I think I can add an intermediate callback just to avoid to call user's callback when the timer is paused.

Comment: Ah yes! Good idea I didn't consider using another callback for "Pausing".